# missing iphone option inside xamania studio

Tags: ios, iphone, installation

I am new to `ios`. I m just keen to learn `iphone`. So i installed `Xamarin` in my Windows 8.When tried to create a new file for `iphone` i did not get any option for `iphone`. I got only android,Asp.net under C#. So can anyone tell me what should i do now to get iphone option inside C#. Have i done anything wrong in installation. or it is not at all possible in windows 8.
I am following [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/)

Answer (score 0):

In windows machine by using only `Xamarin Studio` you can't do iOS development.

You can do this possible by using Visual Studio `Non-Express` Edition.This studio is extensible.Xamarin comes with iOS plugin for Visual Studio but only for its Non-Express Editions.

So,you will need to use non express edition of Visual Studio in order to get iOS plugin ready to work in your Windows 8 machine.Hope this helped you.